# How to Load User Control in Table

Tags: asp.net

I want to add usercontrl to Table Control each time i Press the Button,
I have done this code in Click Event, I got the Control in First Click but after this 
Controls are disappers , can any suggest the solution?
Thanks.

```
if (Session["tbl"] == null)
    {
        Session["tbl"] = Table1;
    }
    else
    {
        Table1 = (Table)Session["tbl"];
    }
    TimeSheetRow tr= LoadControl ("TimeSheetRow.ascx") as TimeSheetRow ;
    tr.ID = "tr" + Table1.Rows.Count;


Session.Add((Session.Count + 1).ToString(), tr);



    Table1.Rows.Add(new TableRow());
    Table1.Rows[Table1.Rows.Count -1].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
    Table1.Rows[Table1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Controls.Add(tr);


    Session["tbl"] = Table1;
```

Comment: what purpose dose (Session.Add((Session.Count + 1).ToString(), tr);) serves?? where is the code which add table1 on page. put it in pre_init so that its view state is available at load time

Comment: Table1 is added at design time, not by code, each time Rows.count is incremented, but on page no effect

Comment: try putting this code in load event if (Session["tbl"] != null)
    {
        Table1=(Table1) Session["tbl"] ;
    }

Comment: same thing happens in load event also

Comment: it would be help full if you can post all load event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you dynamically add a control to the controls collection, on postback you have to re-add that control to the control tree.  So all of the older user controls need to be re-added on page init.  Also, I would highly recommend not using session to store references to the table rows; if you re-add the table rows to the table, viewstate will reload the data within them.